# indentation for nested lists and short labels with enumitem

Tags: indentation, enumitem

I am trying to have a nested list with a label, using the enumitem package with the "shortlabels" option.  But when I add the label "Note" to the list items, the indentation is aligned with the number instead with the start of the label "Note".

```
 \documentclass[]{article}%
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}



\begin{document}

Here's my first list, which has the label ``Note'', but the indentation is too far to the left:

\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
        \begin{enumerate}[{Note} 1:]
        \item First nested item
        \item Second nested item
        \end{enumerate}
\item Third item
\end{itemize}

Here's a second list, showing the proper indentation of the nested list when there is no ``Note'' label:

\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item First nested item
        \item Second nested item
        \end{enumerate}
\item Third item
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ulrike's response provided half of the solution.  The other key is to add "leftmargin=1.2cm" in the enumerate options, in addition to the "align=left" option.

```
    \documentclass[]{article}%
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}



    \begin{document}

    Here's my first list, which has the label ``Note'', but the indentation is too far to the left:

    \begin{itemize}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
                \begin{enumerate}[{Note} 1:, align=left, leftmargin=1.2cm]
                \item First nested item
                \item Second nested item
                \end{enumerate}
    \item Third item
    \end{itemize}

    Here's a second list, showing the proper indentation of the nested list when there is no ``Note'' label:

    \begin{itemize}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
                \begin{enumerate}
                \item First nested item
                \item Second nested item
                \end{enumerate}
    \item Third item
    \end{itemize}


    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

enumerate labels are right aligned. That means that if they get longer they stick out to the left. You can change this with the align key:

```
 \documentclass[]{article}%
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}



\begin{document}

Here's my first list, which has the label ``Note'', but the indentation is too far to the left:

\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
        \begin{enumerate}[{Note} 1:,align=left]
        \item First nested item
        \item Second nested item
        \end{enumerate}
\item Third item
\end{itemize}

Here's a second list, showing the proper indentation of the nested list when there is no ``Note'' label:

\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item First nested item
        \item Second nested item
        \end{enumerate}
\item Third item
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I just add "align=left", the "Note" is aligned directly under "Second item".  Is there a way to have "Note" indented to the right of "Second"?  I want the "N" of "Note" in the first list to start with the same indentation as "1" in the second list.